# Running Cypress tests on Deployments

Tags: cypress, azure-devops-pipelines

We are using Azure DevOps Pipelines. I would like run our Cypress tests on our deployments.  All Cypress docs and examples explain how to run tests on builds, but not deployments.  We cannot run our tests on builds because we do not restore our DB during each build do to the sheer amount of data.

I would like to run the test as the last step of the deployment in parallel using docker containers.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Check if [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/run-cypress-tests-azure-pipelines-jithin-jose-jacob/) helps.